# How do you evaluate the $q$-series of expressions like $j(\tau)^{-1/5}$?

Tags: fourier-series, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function

Klein's $j$-invariant (or the modular function $j$) appears in all introductory texts to modular forms but I have not seen a treatment of how to efficiently work out coefficients for the $q$-expansion of expressions like say, $j(\tau)^{-1/5}$ when the expansion of $j(\tau)$ is known.

One could just treat it by first principles and use the formula for the coefficients in a Fourier series, but that doesn't seem practical here. Is this discussed anywhere? These fractional powers of $j$ appear in the literature but have not seen a canonical explanation.

Comment: Please provide references to your claim "These fractional powers of j appear in the literature". In general, the fractional power of a power series will be a Puiseux series and there are algorithms to calculate its coefficients as in various computer algebra systems.

Comment: @Somos fractional powers of the invariant appear in the study of real weight modular forms.

Comment: You still have not given a specific literature reference.